# interpreting the structure of a matrix

Tags: r

Looking at the structure of my object `brca` in RStudio, I see this:

[image: Data block of R-Studio]

How do I interpret the structure of brca$x?  I can see x is a 2d matrix with 569 x 30 dimensions.  What I have yet to understand is, what does the `..- attr(*, "dimensions")=List of 2` and `.. ..$ : NULL` and `.. ..$ : chr[1:30] "rad...` lines telling me?  Similarly, y is a factor of 569, so I assume y is mapped to `x[1,]'`  Can I reference the contents by index and/or name?

Insights appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr[1:30] "radius_mean" # ...
```

This is telling you the dimension names of your 569 x 30 matrix. Specifically, there are no row names (hence `NULL`), but the 30 columns are named (e.g., the first column is named `"radius_mean"`).

```
$ y: Factor w/ 2 levels "B", "M": 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

What it says on the tin: this is a [factor](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/factors.html) with two levels, "B" and "M". The first six values are all `1`, which means they’re all `"B"`s — the first level of your factor.

To your question about referencing — yes, you can reference the contents by index. e.g., `brca$y[[1]]`, `brca$y[3:6]`, or `brca$y[c(2, 4, 6)]`. You can also reference by value. `brca$y == "B"` will return a logical vector the same length as `brca$y`. You can then use this logical vector to reference or filter other objects: e.g., `brca$x[brca$y == "B"]` will return rows of `brca$x` corresponding to indices where `brca$y` is `"B"`.

Finally, `data.frame(y = brca$y, brca$x)` will return a `data.frame` including `brca$y` and all columns in `brca$x`.

Comment: Thank you zephryl !  The size of y came from `length(brca$y)`  You've made this clearer for me.  I appreciate the examples of the various reference styles you have included.

Comment: @NocturnalOne you’re welcome! I added some additional info to my answer in case it’s helpful.